# data loss with parallel enabled pipelined function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a pipelined function that loads data into file.

The following is the code of function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DATA_UNLOAD
   ( p_source                 IN SYS_REFCURSOR,
      p_filename       IN VARCHAR2,
        p_directory      IN VARCHAR2
       ) RETURN dump_ntt PIPELINED PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION p_source BY ANY)
AS
   TYPE row_ntt IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);
   v_rows       row_ntt;
   v_file       UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   v_buffer     VARCHAR2(32767);
   v_sid        VARCHAR(255);
   v_name       VARCHAR2(255);
   v_lines      PLS_INTEGER := 0;
   v_start_dttm TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE:= SYSTIMESTAMP;
   v_end_dttm   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;
   c_eol        CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := CHR(10);
   c_eollen     CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH(c_eol);
   c_maxline    CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 32767;   
BEGIN
  --v_sid := lpad(sys_context('USERENV', 'sid'), 10, '0');
  v_name:=p_filename;
  LOOP 
     if utl_file.is_open(v_file)
     then
        utl_file.fclose(v_file); 
     end if;
    v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(p_directory, v_name, 'A', c_maxline);
    FETCH p_source BULK COLLECT INTO v_rows LIMIT 100;
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_rows.COUNT LOOP
     IF LENGTH(v_buffer) + c_eollen + LENGTH(v_rows(i)) <= c_maxline THEN
        v_buffer := v_buffer || c_eol || v_rows(i);
     ELSE
        IF v_buffer IS NOT NULL THEN
           UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, v_buffer);
         END IF;
        v_buffer := v_rows(i);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    v_lines := v_lines + v_rows.COUNT;
    EXIT WHEN p_source%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE p_source;   
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, v_buffer);
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);
   v_end_dttm := SYSTIMESTAMP;
   --PIPE ROW (dump_ot(v_name, p_directory, v_lines, v_sid, v_start_dttm, v_end_dttm));
   --RETURN ;
END;
```

i call the function this way.

```
SELECT * from table(DATA_UNLOAD(
                         CURSOR(select /*+ PARALLEL */ a || b || c from sample_table),                                     
                        'sample.txt',
                         '99_DIR'));
```

a real life select that i pass as a parameter to function returns 30000 rows, but when i use the function to load the result into a file some rows are lost. During the execution with PARALLEL hint there are 24 parallel sessions, and i dont want to make it less. My guess is that the problem is in parallel execution, because when i dont use PARALLEL hint no data is lost. Can anyone suggest something to get rid of that problem without removing the hint?

Comment: In your code, add some details using `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO`, then while you call the pipeline function, check what exactly is happening in the `session` from `CLIENT_INFO`.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you are attempting to write to a file from 24 simultaneous sessions?

Comment: @LalitKumarB can you please specify how exactly this will work, because i never used it and i dont imagine how it will help me.

Comment: @APC i run the function with PARALLEL hint so it opens 24 sessions and yes all the sessions write their parts to the same file.

Comment: @arminrock, what I mean is, if you feed the details in client_info, you would see in each of the 24 sessions what is going on. You can put the record count to know how many records have been processed in that session. What I am thinking is, few of those sessions might not be actually doing anything. So, if you see the `client_info` in `v$session`, you will actually come to know what's going on in each session.

Comment: @LalitKumarB okay i got it. But the same information i can get from the function itself, if you look there is a pipe row part which exists as a comment in the code of function, so with that i can see the count of lines each individual session has worked with, and the sum of that counts is the actual count of the rows that select returns, so i guess sessions work with all the data but while appending to file some data is lost. Maybe i again understood something wrong, if so please provide an example where in the code and how to add DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO to get good information.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you are wiping out your own database as each parallel execution is writing to the same file at the same time.  If the database server is running on Linux, try setting up a named pipe and write to that instead to see if that gets around your problem.

Comment: Same problem here.  
No files writing , but only pure sql like 

```sql
SELECT /*+ parallel(3) */ *
FROM ( 
select * from table_name0
union all 
select * from table_name1
) 
```

With  the hint /*+ parallel(3) */ * in sql, the last row will be lost .
So,this's a oracle bug I can tell.

My solution is do not use   parallel hint any more

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are creating sample.txt with Append mode - you have 24 parallel sessions each writing to it.  I always use unique filenames by appending the SID to your variable:

```
SELECT sid INTO v_sid FROM v$mystat WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
v_name := p_filename || '_' || v_sid || '.dat';
```

Depending on the # of parallel sessions you should 1 to many files with the format sample_*nnnn*.txt where *nnnn* is the SID number.

Comment: yes that works, but i needed  the result into one single file. I could not find the reason for that kind of behavior when doing for one file,  but i could find the  optimal limit for bulk collect  and parallelism and the server, so since than i just had no single problem. Thank for the response.